# Show JSON data on loop in div using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using jQuery and JSON to get data from database

```
$("#openNotification").on('click', function(e)
{
    ID = "a";
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "notificationDetail",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            designationID: ID
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
            $(".processingNotification").hide();

            var jSonLength = jsonStr.length;

            for (var i=0; i<jSonLength; i++)
            {
                var userAvatar = jsonStr[0].userAvatar;

                var newrow = "<div class='subNotification'><img src='assets/img/avatar/"+userAvatar+"'/></div>";


            }


            $(".opened_page").html(newrow);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="opened_page"></div>
```

When I click `#openNotification` I can see the jSon data from PHP

[image]

But when I want to display the data to `.opened_page` it only show 1 data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are replacing with new value, code should be

```
var newrow = '';
for (var i=0; i<jSonLength; i++)
{
     var userAvatar = jsonStr[0].userAvatar;
     newrow += "<div class='subNotification'><img src='assets/img/avatar/"+userAvatar+"'/></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery append() function here.

For eg.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jSonLength; i++){
   var userAvatar = jsonStr[i].userAvatar;
   $(".opened_page").append("<div class='subNotification'><img src='assets/img/avatar/"+userAvatar+"'/></div>");
}
```

So your final code would be like,

```
$("#openNotification").on('click', function(e){
    ID = "a";
    $.ajax({
        url: "notificationDetail",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            designationID: ID
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr){
            $(".processingNotification").hide();
            var jSonLength = jsonStr.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < jSonLength; i++){
                var userAvatar = jsonStr[i].userAvatar;
                $(".opened_page").append("<div class='subNotification'><img src='assets/img/avatar/"+userAvatar+"'/></div>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```